# Set case sensitive Windows environment variables in Perl

Tags: windows, perl, shell, msys

I am trying to set some Windows environment variables in Perl with case sensitivity in order to use them in a shell script.

However, I noticed that the environment variables are all in uppercase when I try to use them in lowercase in a shell script called from Perl with `system` command and run with Msys.

For example, the following script:

```
#!perl

system "echo echo TOTO=\$TOTO > toto.sh";
system "echo echo Titi=\$Titi >> toto.sh";
system "echo echo TITI=\$TITI >> toto.sh";
$ENV{'TOTO'}="0+0";
$ENV{'Titi'}="Not toto!";
system("sh toto.sh");
```

returns (while run in Msys) the following output:

```
TOTO=0+0
Titi=
TITI=Not toto!
```

Does anybody know whether this is possible in Windows (i.e. how to set the environment variable `Titi` and not `TITI`)?

Thanks

Comment: Which system (OS) are you using? In my case (OS X and Linux) it works (I just had to quote the dollars in the script creation statements). E.g. system "echo echo TOTO='\$TOTO'> toto.sh";

Comment: I get: TOTO=0+0,
Titi=Not toto!,
TITI=

Comment: I use Windows, unfortunately... I will update the question.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a `sh`. Are you running Cygwin?

Comment: I am running Msys. But I suppose same problem happens with Cygwin. => added in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be that it is not possible to do: Windows will only use the uppercase variables.

The way I did was to temporarily transform the script by replacing variables with their upper-case equivalent and switch them back to the previous state after using them.

In my case, I had to deal with the variables exported from the shell script `Run_Session.sh`. I have created a Perl script to perform the uppercase replacement and this is the result.

```
###############################
## SUBROUTINE uc_variables   ##
#-----------------------------#
# This subroutine convert the environment variables exported 
# by the top level script to upper case, and can revert the operation.
#
# Input:
# -----
# $mode: "ON" (default) or "OFF"
#
# Output:
# ------
# N/A
#-----------------------#
#########################
sub uc_variables {
    my $mode=shift;
    chdir $Bin;
    if ($mode eq "OFF") {
        foreach my $bak (glob "{*,*/*}.sh.bak") {
            (my $orig = $bak)=~s/\.bak//;
            move($bak,$orig);
        }
    } else {
        #Check if back-up already exists
        uc_variables("OFF") if (-e "Run_Session.sh.bak");
        #List variables to update
        my %uc_var;
        open RUN_SESSION,"<Run_Session.sh" or die "Error while reading Run_Session.sh ($!)\n";
        map { /export\s+(\w*[a-z]\w*)/ and ($uc_var{$1}=uc($1))=~s/Directory/DIR/i } <RUN_SESSION>;
        close RUN_SESSION;
        #Replace variables
        foreach my $shell (glob "{*,*/*}.sh") {
            #Back-up
            copy($shell,"$shell.bak");
            #Read data
            open SHELL,"<$shell" or die "Error while reading $shell ($!)\n";
            my $SHELL = join("", <SHELL>);
            close SHELL;
            #Replace
            map { $SHELL=~s/$_/$uc_var{$_}/g } keys %uc_var;
            #Print
            open SHELL,">$shell" or die "Error while writing in $shell ($!)\n";
            print SHELL $SHELL;
            close SHELL;
        }
    }
} #end of uc_variables
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows environment variable identifiers are case-independent in the same way as Windows files.

`Titi` and `TITI` are both names for the same variable, and its value can be acccessed through either `$ENV{TITI}` or `$ENV{Titi}` in Perl. Likewise `echo %TITI%` and `echo %Titi%` on the command line will give the same result.

If you explain why it is that you need case-sensitive environment variable names then we may be able to help you.

Comment: I try to call them from a shell script that uses lowercase. I have limited access to the shell script so I try to avoid modifying the shell script.

Comment: Does the shell script use upper- and lower-case versions of the same variable name? If not, then you shouldn't need to distinguish between them, but if it does then I don't think you have any choice but to modify the script. Where does your `sh` come from? It's not standard on Windows.

Comment: The script only use one version which is partially lowercased (like Titi). I have Msys installed and run shell from there.

Comment: Echo can be used to store environment variables in a local variable. E.g. 

        `my $ti  = \`"echo %TITI%"\`;`

Comment: @Underverse: It is pointless to shell out to `echo` when the whole thing can be done within Perl with `my $ti = $ENV{TITI}`

Answer (score 0):

The following should apply independently of the casing problem.

Let's take the first line:

```
system "echo echo TOTO=\$TOTO > toto.sh";
```

If you call

```
echo echo TOTO=\$TOTO
```

on your command line, the output will be:

```
echo TOTO=\$TOTO
```

which seems to be, what you want.

However, the line you are calling with system is first interpreted by perl, so your escaped \$ becomes a $.

The output then depends on the current value of $TOTO (before you set the environment variable in the script), which is probably empty.

You should change all those system calls to be single quoted:

```
 system 'echo echo TOTO=\$TOTO > toto.sh';
```

If you do this, you will get the following output:

```
TOTO=0+0
Titi=
TITI=not TOTO
```

Titi is empty, because you didn't assign a value to it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a long answer. However, I disagree as I want to send to the command line "echo TOTO=$TOTO" so the call to system is correct. Your last suggestion returns (at least on Windows), the following: TOTO=$TOTO. It is true however that I could have modified the line as: "system 'echo echo TOTO=\$TOTO > toto.sh';" so simplify. The problem I have seems to be related to Windows environment variables being stored uppercase.

Comment: Sorry for that, I tested on linux, with bash as shell.
What is "sh" in your case? Do you have Cygwin installed?